# Group By on Containable models using cake php

Tags: cakephp

Hi i have model logo with the following associations

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Attachment' => array(
        'className'=>'Attachment',
        'foreignKey'=>'attachment_id'
    ),
    'Employee' => array(
        'className'=>'Employee',
        'foreignKey'=>'employee_id'
    )
);

var $hasMany = array(
    'Voting' => array(
        'className'=>'Voting',
        'foreignKey'=>'program_id'
    )
);
```

i wrote a query in the following way it throws error

```
$PrgCond['contain'] = array(
    'Attachment',
    'Voting' => array(
        'fields' => array(
            'logo_program_id',
            'COUNT(employee_id) as noOfEmps'
        ),
        'group' => array('LogoVoting.logo_program_id')
    ), 
    'Employee' => array(
        'fields' => array('id', 'employee_number', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    )
);
$logoPrgDatas = $this->Program->find('all',$PrgCond);
 Thrown Error is 

SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'LogoVoting.logo_program_id' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Is Program associated with LogoVoting? It would be nice if you paste all your associations.

Comment: doesn't contain only look for model associations and fields ? i don't think you can put group or conditions on the 'Voting' array level

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but still comes up in Google results.. 
I had a similar issue and found out that you cannot use **group** in the Model find options when you have associations or either use containable behavior(which uses associations) in cakephp 1.* or 2.*.

However, this issue is fixed in cakephp 3.* by using query builder! :)

Comment: can you explain how this issue can be resolved in cakephp3.*. I am struggling to get only grouped results in contained associations but not getting it.

Answer (score -1):

It's a good idea to reference the model in your fields. For example, when you are using a column in a condition or a fields array, you should call it `Model.column_name`.

Having said that, the problem you are having is most likely related to the group:

`'group' => array('LogoVoting.logo_program_id')`

There is no `LogoVoting` in your model. It should be:

`'group' => array('Voting.logo_program_id')`

So I would update the query to be:

```
$PrgCond['contain'] = array(
    'Attachment',
    'Voting' => array(
        'fields' => array(
            'Voting.logo_program_id',
            'COUNT(Voting.employee_id) as noOfEmps',
        ),
        'group' => array('Voting.logo_program_id'),
    ), 
    'Employee' => array(
        'fields' => array(
            'Employee.id',
            'Employee.employee_number',
            'Employee.first_name',
            'Employee.last_name',
        ),
    ),
);
```